# How to configure woocommerce to work with wildcard certificate and wp multisite?

Tags: ssl, wildcard, woocommerce

I have wordpress multisite version 3.5 and `woocommerce 2.0.2` with wildcard certificate.

I need to know if it is possible to force ssl on checkout page using `wildcard ssl`.
When I force ssl on the checkout page of the main site it works ok..

But when I do it on a *subdomain* with mapping plugin, I lose all the css of the checkout page and chrome display a certificate error.

Do I need a multi-domain certificate?

Can I have them working together?

What is the best way to go about this?

I will need SSL on checkout pages of each blog.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if it is possible to force ssl on checkout page using wildcard ssl

You can use the [Wordpress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin to force SSL on the relevant pages.

> I lose all the css of the checkout page and chrome display a certificate error.

You may need to create rewrites so that your assets are being served from the https subdomain: see [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10764/anyone-figured-out-how-to-use-wordpress-multisite-with-domain-mapping-ssl) for an example of it being done with subdirectory mapping.